# How to append content to html from an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

What I am trying to do is to click on a link that will dynamically append the value of a data attribute to a different div. The problem is that it always append the content (duplicates). What I want to reach is to replace the content from an array. My code:

```
 <a href='#' class="hotel" data-hotel-name='Holiday Inn'>Add to favourites</a>
<a href='#' class="hotel" data-hotel-name='Hilton'>Add to favourites</a>


<div id="hotel-box">
<!-- add the hotel names here -->
</div>

<script>

var hotelName = [];    
$('.hotel').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    hotelName.push( $(this).data('hotel-name') );

     var html = '<ul style="background-color: green">';
    jQuery.each($.unique(hotelName), function(index, item) {
                html += '<li>something ' + item + '</li>';
    });

    html += '</ul>';
    $('#hotel-box').append(html);

    console.log(html);

});

</script>
```

The output when clicked on those two links above should be:

```
<div id="hotel-box">
  <ul>
     <li>Hilton</li>
     <li>Holiday Inn</li>
  </ul>
</div
```

Comment: `$('#hotel-box').append(html);` appends - `$('#hotel-box').html(html);` will replace

Comment: use document.getElementById("hotel-box").innerHTML = html;

Comment: It works! Great. That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: @Roman - You will notice that duplicates will also be added if a user clicks on a favourite more than once in an alternating fashion. You can alleviate this by using `$.unique(hotelName.sort())` or as per this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Psylene/gt65gyjp/)